# aws - how to access opsWorks app with ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, load-balancing

My app was easy deployed on 3 instances using OpsWorks. I can Access it using instance IP's fine.

My question is: how can I access it using load balancer?

ELB says all 3 instances are InService, but typing public DNS on browser, it loads forever and shows nothing.

Testing ELB public DNS on http://whatsmydns.com it shows IP's that aren't from my instances.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have added Public DNS to my app as hostname.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to check:

1. Check that your load balancer listeners are configured to listen
   and pass traffic to the same port that the instance is listening on
   (for example http traffic 80 => http 80, https traffic 443 => https
   443)
2. Check that the security group of the webservers allows
   traffic from the loadbalancer. Though if you can access your instances directly via browser, I'm guessing they are open to 0.0.0.0/0 so shouldn't be an issue here?
3. Check that security group of the load balancer allows access to public on all needed ports (typically 80 and 443)
4. Check that elb healthcheck is not failing (under elb
   instances you can see if the instances are in service or not) If it
   says "Out of service" that's the problem. You need to make sure that
   healthcheck URL is accessible and returns 200.

The DNS of your load balancer is different from your instances - it returns the IP addresses of the instances that the load balancer is running on, AWS usually has at least 3 servers behind the scenes for that.